# How to read a sequence of integers from Standard-input with Stdin?

Tags: java, stdin

I'm using java on command lines, i want to write a programm that could filter and removes the duplicates of a sequence of integers but first of all i don't know how to use StdIn to read a sequnce of Integers.

The Programm should read values from Standard input until it reach the EOF-Sequence with the help of StdIn.

Input and Output example on Command line:

```
$ echo 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 4 6 2 1 | java RemoveDuplicates
1 2 1 3 4 6 2 1
```

I've tried to convert the Integers to an array

```
int[] n = StdIn.readAllInts();
```

but it doesn't work when tried to print it out.
can anybody give me some tips?

Comment: java RemoveDuplicates | echo 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 4 6 2 1 
?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to catch it as a string with a normal scanner:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = in.nextLine();
```

sometimes the second line don't work for some inputs, so you can also try:

```
String line = in.next();
```

to get the numbers as integers you can use inputStream, but I'm not sure how will work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

```
    int testNum;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("number of elements to be inserted");
    testNum = in.nextInt();




    //Add items
    for ( int i = 0; i<testNum; i++)
    {
          set.add(in.nextInt());
    }

    //Print all element
    Iterator it = set.iterator();     
    while(it.hasNext()){
           System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

I hope to have helped you

Comment: For more information, see java documentation(Set,Iterator)

Answer (score 0):

Sample program below, this removes the duplicate entries but still retains the order.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the sequence with spaces e.g. 1 3 5 3 1 1 3 5 ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = input.split("\\s+");

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
        String item = numbers[x];
        if (result.contains(item)) continue;
        result.add(item);
    }
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", result));
}
```

And output sample is:

```
Enter the sequence with spaces e.g. 1 3 5 3 1 1 3 5 
1 1 2 2 1 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 11 11 12 12 1 1 6 6 2 1 //sequence entered
1 2 3 4 11 12 6 // sample result
```

Comment: You are removing only consecutive duplicates

Answer (score 0):

`Stdin` is not needed.

By calling

```
java RemoveDuplicates 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 4 6 2 1
```

It assigns `String[] args` to an array of all those values.

If you want to remove duplicates, put them in a `Set`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> uniq = new HashSet<>();
    for (String s : args) {
        uniq.add(s);
    }
    System.out.println(uniq);
}
```